# How To Identify Inefficient Code Within a Function

Tags: performance, debugging, performance-testing

I was recently asked this question during an interview & apart from `console.log` & `debugger`, I wasn't able to give more tools / options for this problem.

The question was: I am reviewing code & I find that the code is causing performance issues. The code is one very lengthy function. How would I go about identifying the line/s of code causing the performance issues.

Thinking about it, now, post the interview, the only other solution that comes to mind is to break the code into tinier functions & analyse. However, I wonder whats the best solution to this problem, not only for the interviews, it would help me be more mindful of options available when I do encounter this problem in real life. (unfortunately, the interviewer was quite non-communicative & clearly wanted to go through the questions as quickly as possible).

Thanks

Comment: Use a profiler.

Comment: It might make sense to do some [algorithmic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) if the code is highly mathematical/algorithmic. That involves determining the time and space complexities of the different parts of your code, and figuring out alternatives for the inefficient bits.

Comment: @AdamBrown this is one big function. To my knowledge, profiler wouldn't help with the code within the function.

Comment: It depends on the language and the profiler - most (good) profilers in most languages can do this to some extent. It largely depends on the profiler settings, and whether your problem is algorithmic in nature (i.e. there is something inefficient in terms of the time complexity) or whether it is simply performance polishing that's required. The reason being that line-by-line profiling is more expensive in terms of overheads, so will only typically spot things where the order of the algorithm is wrong. But to get more information, you'd need to be more language specific.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is to store the current time right before the infamous function call, then in that function, store the current time before and after strategic places where you think the culprit is. At the end, print the time that it took to execute these parts that are in between the strategic places and you will have a good idea of where the system is spending much of its time.